# Facebook Graph API - automatic login for an image upload

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading

Here's the problem:

We have a system that works offline, without internet access. However, it's supposed to offer users function so they can choose photos they would like to upload to Facebook later, when the system gets online.

We can collect Facebook username and password from the user. But Facebook requires an access token, that's given by the login dialog on their website. Also, the user has to give his permission to the application on Facebook.

Is it possible somehow to automate these things, so the system can use the username and password to upload the photos user has selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for certain, however I would imagine not.
I'm pretty sure its done to prevent anything posting without your permission.

it prevents malicious programs from posting false status updates or posting inappropriate pictures on your profile etc.
obviously this isn't what you're trying to do, but its all caught in the same net unfortunately.

I'd guess the best you could do is store the request and re-ask the user next time they're able to log on to facebook if its ok to still post the update, and get their express permission.